# maven plugin configuration

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

When writing a Maven plugin, you can configure various parameters within the mojo class, e.g.

```
/**
 * The path to the properties files.
 * 
 * @parameter expression="${project.build.directory}"
 */
private File buildDir;
```

Is there a reference that lists all the available project properties (e.g. ${project.build.directory})? For example, how do I get the value of the resources directory?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reference that lists all the available project properties (e.g. ${project.build.directory})?

The already mentioned [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) is the place to go. Also be sure to check [PLXUTILS-37](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXUTILS-37) that introduced the following syntax:

- `project.dependencies[0]` if `dependencies` is a `java.util.List` object or an array object
- `project.dependenciesAsMap(dep1)` if `dependenciesAsMap` is a `java.util.Map` object

> For example, how do I get the value of the resources directory?

Why would you need this? Resources are typically copied to `${project.build.directory}` and you should interact with them from there.

But if you really want to go this way, don't forget that `project.build.resources` holds a `List` of `Resource` (so you might need `${project.build.resources[0].directory}`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is `${project.build.resources[0]}` the correct way to refer to the first (and in my case, only) resource dir?

Comment: @Don This will indeed give you the first [Resource](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Resource.html) object. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).